# Java BigDecimal subtraction results in zero in debugger, but does not apply the result to variable

Tags: java, android, math, bigdecimal

I have a section of code that does a running count of payments to see if rent has been paid for a property, code is as follows:

```
BigDecimal remainingAmount = MathUtilities.roundBigDecimal(new BigDecimal(amountDue.getAmount().doubleValue()));

    for(RentPayment payment : this.rentPayments) {
        remainingAmount = remainingAmount.subtract(payment.getAmountPaid().getAmount());
    }

    return remainingAmount;
```

So here, all that needs to happen is remaining amount needs to be returned so we know how much rent has been paid for a particular invoice. When I run this in the debugger, it does 235.66 - 235.66, with the logical result of 0:

```
remainingAmount.subtract(payment.getAmountPaid().getAmount());
```

However, when running this code normally, the result, no matter how many payments of 235.66, is always 235.66, event though I'm explicitly setting remainingAmount. Is there something I'm missing? Every question I've looked at seems to suggest I'm doing this correctly.

Edit: Just to show I'm not crazy or missing something obvious:
[image]

And:
[image]

Comment: are you sure rentPaments isnt empty?

Comment: 100%, I've stepped through this about 50 times, everything seems to run exactly how it should, except that the result of the subtraction, though correct, doesn't stick to remainingAmount.

Comment: I see no reason to see why this won't work, but as this isn't a [mcve], I cannot confirm it for myself.  Can you provide something I can paste into my IDE and verify?

Comment: If you plug in 235.66 for remaining amount and payment amount instead of those object getters, it'll be identical to mine (There's just one payment), see my edit for what the debugger has to say about this code.

Comment: The first and third of the blue statements in your debugger are assigning `remainingAmount`.

Comment: @JoeC I'm laughing so hard right now, I've literally never had that be an issue for me in my 6 years of dev, so I didn't even consider something like that....thank you so much for that, that was the issue.

Comment: Is remainigAmount returned correctly from a method- if so do you use it properly afterwards.

Comment: @user1653941 See JoeC's comment, it was because a watch I had used to validate the result of the operation was left in and it was overriding what my code was doing.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was because a watch I had used to validate the result of the operation was left in and it was overriding what my code was doing, this was a simple user error, closing out this question.